# Outlook 7 align image and text on same line

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Having the following HTML markup in my email template

```
<p>
    <a class="arrowlink" href="https://link" style="font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; line-height: 22px; height: 26px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 18px; color:#5cc5ed;">
        <img src="/arrow_link.png" style="vertical-align:middle;max-width:20px !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; width: 20px; height:20px; margin-right:5px; !margin-top: 15px; mso-margin-top-alt:15px; !padding-top: 15px; border:0;" align="absbottom" width="22px" height="auto" class="img-arrow">
        <span style="display: inline-block; line-height: 22px; height: 22px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" class="link-text">My Link</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

I try to align the image and the span content on the same line which will work in most of email clients but in outlook the image and span content are not aligned correctly.

Is there any workaround for this without to use any kind of tables for outlook 2007[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no reliable way to ensure consistency across all email clients, especially when it comes to margin & padding. You just have to find a compromise that you can live with.

In my experience, the best thing is to keep it as simple as possible and try to minimise the amount of styling you need to do.

**Tables:**  Unless you have a *very* basic design, I'm afraid you *have* to use tables for emails - even for the current modern email clients, never mind Outlook 2007 :) Designing for email goes against nearly every good HTML development practice we know (tables, inline styles etc).

**Image Alignment:** My suggestion is to change the image itself to include any padding / margin instead of trying to add it in the CSS, which can be handled differently by different email clients.

**FYI: Outlook 2007 Usage & Support:**

- Microsoft ended support for Outlook 2007 in 2017.
- In 2015, approx 16% of emails sent to Outlook were opened in Outlook 2007.
- This dropped to 10% in 2017 (the last year of support).

As support ended in Oct 2017, I would expect that the number of users is much lower now.

While I wouldn't suggest ignoring it, I would emphasise design on the more popular email clients unless you know that a large percentage of your recipients have

Comment: Thanks for this detailed feedback!